# react pass object key as prop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to pass array of strings from parent function component to child function component. At the child component the array should reflect the object key.

For example, send the following array from a parent BY PROP:
let colors = ['red','green','white']

and at the child component I have the following variable:

```
let arr = [config.red, config.green, config.white, config.blue];
```

**I want to take the ".red, .green, .white" from the props** and then go over the config variable below:

```
const config: {
red: {
    base: string;
    icon: any;
    name: string;
    target: string;
};
white: {
    base: number;
    icon: any;
    name: string;
    target: string;
```

...

Be very glad for any help. Best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the array of keys to your component...

```jsx
<Child colors={colors} />
```

then reduce that array to the matching keys from `config`

```js
const arr = props.colors.reduce(
  (acc, key) => (key in config ? [...acc, config[key]] : acc),
  []
);
```

I'm using `reduce()` instead of a simple `map()` in order to filter out keys that might not be in `config`.

Answer (score 0):

`<Child colors={["red", "green", "white"]} />`

and inside `Child`, you can get the respective `config` object, using `map` and iterating over it

```
const arr = props.colors.map((item,index)=>{
      
       return config[item];
})
```